# Global variable python with leetcode

Tags: python

I'm currently dealing with Climbing Stairs problem in Leetcode and my solution is to use recursion. To return a counter without being reset I have to use global Count.
Here is my code:

```
count =0
class Solution:
    def climbStairs(self, n: int) -> int:
        global count
        root = Tree()
        root.data = n
        if root.data - 1 >= 0:       
            root.left= self.climbStairs(n-1)
        if root.data -2 >= 0:     
            root.right= self.climbStairs(n-2)
        if (root.left == None) and (root.right == None):
            count+= 1
        return count
```

In the single run, every case seems okay but when I submmited it, it turned out to be wrong, I realized because the global Count doesn't reset to every test case (input = 2 -> output =2, input=3 -> output =5 (it should be output = 3 but get 5 because (2 from the previous test case + 3 from the current test case). Since leetcode does not let me change the function parameters, is there anyway I can handle this issue. Thank you alot

Comment: I don't think you count on everyone knowing what you mean by `Climbing Stairs problem in Leetcode`.

Comment: move your logic to another function and use your `climbStairs` function to reset the count and call the new function.

Comment: Or put the counter as a default variable into the function definition `def climbStairs(self, n, count=0)` and change the rest of the logic accordingly

Comment: You haven't described the desired output, the current output, what your code is meant to do, or provided a [mcve]. I'm not familiar with LeetCode, is that global variable necessary? As an aside, recursion is rarely the right answer in Python.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that if you run your solution against a range of test case inputs 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, etc. you'll recognize the pattern/sequence the outputs make, and figure out a simpler approach. But if you want to do it the way you're doing, one way to go about it would be to use an instance variable to keep track of the count, and a helper function that actually does the recursion, for the climbStairs function to call, for example:

```
class Solution:
    def count_ways(self, n):
        root = Tree()
        root.data = n
        if root.data - 1 >= 0:
            root.left = self.count_ways(n - 1)
        if root.data - 2 >= 0:
            root.right = self.count_ways(n - 2)
        if (root.left == None) and (root.right == None):
            self.count += 1
        return self.count

    def climbStairs(self, n):
        self.count = 0
        self.count_ways(n)
        return self.count
```